# Create JTable in a JPanel and add row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

On my program I've dinamically created a JFrame that contains a JPanel called `jp`. jp also contains a JTable that I would like to fill with some rows.

```
case KeyEvent.VK_R:
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Snake v2.0 - Rankings");
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));

    JTable table = new JTable();
    JScrollPane tableContainer = new JScrollPane(table);
    jp.add(tableContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    tm.addRow(new Object[] {"#","Player","Score","Date"});

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.getContentPane().add(jp);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true); 
break;
```

This is my code. When I press `R` on the keyboard, the JFrame with that JPanel inside appears but the table doesnt ([picture](http://prntscr.com/1ckif0)). What could I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First thing is you haven't added column names to your table.

change this

```
DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
tm.addRow(new Object[] {"#","Player","Score","Date"});
```

to

**EDIT**

```
 DefaultTableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[] {"#","Player","Score","Date"},0);
 table.setModel(tm);
```

and to add row

```
tm.addRow(new Object[]{1,"XXX","99","2013-06-29"});
```

Comment: yeah I fixed it by myself ;)

Answer (score 3):

//Setting the table and Scroll Bars in jpanel

```
DefaultTableModel table_model = new DefaultTableModel(addressData, new String[]{"First Name",    "Surname", "Home Number", "Mobile Number", "Address", "Postcode"});
JTable table = new JTable(this.table_model);
table.setBounds(130, 40, 200, 200);
jp.add(new JScrollPane(table, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS));
```